# Windows powershell команда, открывающая/закрывающая дисковод

Tags: vbscript

Почему такой код открывает закрытый дисковод, но не закрывает открытый

```
Set oWMP = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7" )
Set colCDROMs = oWMP.cdromCollection
colCDROMs.Item(0).Eject
```

А такой закрывает открытый, а закрытый - открывает и закрывает.

```
Set oWMP = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7" )
Set colCDROMs = oWMP.cdromCollection
colCDROMs.Item(0).Eject
colCDROMs.Item(0).Eject
```

Как вообще работает эта команда Eject?

Comment: Что-то код в вопросе больше на VBScript похож чем на Powershell...

Comment: @PavelMayorov спасибо, поменял.

Comment: А в заголовке? )

Answer (score -1):

В официальной [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562589(v=vs.85).aspx) для метода такого же типа сказано, дословно: "Если дисковод открыт, этот метод закрывает его". И что-то мне подсказывает, что та конструкция использует именно ваш метод. Для того, чтобы сразу после открытия дисковод не закрывался, необходимо сделать нечто вроде такого (код не мой, нагуглен, но само условие вам стоило бы взять). Сейчас же у вас по логике дисковод открывается, сразу после этого вызывается тот же метод, который логично закрывает его

```
[CmdletBinding()] 
param( 
[switch]$Eject, 
[switch]$Close 
) 
try { 
    $Diskmaster = New-Object -ComObject IMAPI2.MsftDiscMaster2 
    $DiskRecorder = New-Object -ComObject IMAPI2.MsftDiscRecorder2 
    $DiskRecorder.InitializeDiscRecorder($DiskMaster) 
    if ($Eject) { 
        $DiskRecorder.EjectMedia() 
    } elseif($Close) { 
        $DiskRecorder.EjectMedia() 
    } 
} catch { 
    Write-Error "Failed to operate the disk. Details : $_" 
}
```

Comment: Если дисковод закрыт, то второй скрипт работает действительно понятно как. Но почему при уже открытом дисководе оба примера ведут себя так странно?

Comment: Что вы понимаете под странно? При открытом дисководе этот метод его закроет и все